# UIView animateWithDuration and user interaction

Tags: ios, animation, user-interface

I am running an animation on the iPhone with the below recursive function. When I animate, user interaction is blocked (and when the animation is done, user interaction works). I have been trying to enable user interaction, and have tried

- passing the flag [`UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction) to `animateWithDuration`.
- defining a function called `touchesBegan` as of [this website](http://littlebigthinkers.com/post/interacting-with-an-animating-uiview). This function is never called (and called in other views when I tap the screen).
- running the animation on a different thread with `dispatch_async` and `dispatch_sync` as [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490286/does-dispatch-asyncdispatch-get-main-queue-wait-until-done/17490329#17490329) specifies. I have tried several methods but am not even sure if it'll work.
- putting a UIButton in to detect taps. The function it's linked to isn't called for ~1-2 seconds.

To me, that all sounds like user interaction isn't enabled. How can it be responsive while this animation is running?

This animation is rather long and complex -- it's the whole reason this app exists. Each `longAndComplicatedCalculation` takes about 1s and this function is called ~30 times.

```
- (void)startAnimation:(dispatch_block_t)block withUIBlock:(dispatch_block_t)uiBlock iteration:(int)N{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 delay:0.0
                 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent)
                 animations:^(void) {
                         [block invoke];
                         [uiBlock invoke];
                  }
                  completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                       if(FINISHED_IF && N<N_MAX) {
                          __weak id weakSelf = self;
                          [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                              [weakSelf startAnimation:block withUIBlock:uiBlock iteration:N+1];
                          }];
                        }
                  }
     ];
}
```

This function is called with

```
[self startAnimation:^{
    imageChange = [self longAndComplicatedCalculation];
} withUIBlock:^{
    self.imageView.image = imageChange;
}
iteration:1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling both blocks (the block and the uiBlock) from the main thread. If your longAndComplicatedCalculation is blocking the thread the behaviour is normal. You should call your calculation in a separate thread and from there after finishing call the UIThread to initiate the animation.

To make it more clear, this is the way I would do it (without having your exact implementation and testing):

considering your image is declared as property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *changedImage;
```

when you call the animation you can do it like

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(updateImage) toTarget:nil withObject:nil];
```

and in the function you do the calculation and afterwards call the animation on the UIThread:

```
- (void)updateImage {
    self.changedImage = [self longAndComplicatedCalculation];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self doAnimationAndChangeImage];
    }];
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This answer, though a bit obscure, is correct. It sounds like it is not the animation that is blocking the user interface: it's the calculation that is blocking the entire main thread. And something must be done about this, since if you block the main thread for long enough, your app will be summarily killed by the WatchDog process.

Comment: I have tried throwing the calculation on a background thread but run into issues with assigning self.imageView.image in the main thread. I'm also unsure how animateWithDuration works with dispatch_async. Could you provide an example?