# UITextView text content doesn't start from the top

Tags: objective-c, xcode, text, uitextview

I have a long text coming from my JSON file but when I click the link from my UITableViewCell to go to my UIViewController page, the UITextView text loads the string content but it does not show the content from the beginning and I have to scroll up all the time.

What I need to do?

Comment: Have you tried setting the contentOffset to (0,0)?

Comment: You can edit this question.  Below the tags you see 'edit'. click that to edit. I got a suggestion for an edit but feel the user should edit the question.

Comment: check out this page and see if one of these solutions works for you. Most everything on here is on there and more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234242/how-do-i-force-a-uitextview-to-scroll-to-the-top-every-time-i-change-the-text If you have questions be specific in what is going on, working, not working what you tried.

Comment: Here is the link with my problem: [link](http://www.ornilosantiago.com/ios/example.jpg)

Comment: the only solution that worked for me was from [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28377727/2115904) from another post

Answer (score 161):

I had the same problem, and turns out I had to set the content offset in viewDidLayoutSubviews for it to take effect. I'm using this code to display attributed static text.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [self.yourTextView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
}
```

**SWIFT 3:**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: Of all the answers, this one works the best. In addition, if your UITextView text starts somewhere toward the vertical middle of the text view then adding the following to viewDidLoad will fix that too: self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

Comment: The interesting thing is, that offuttjillian's solution did work for me, but the solution given by you @Wizkid and Glenn makes it even worse for me on iOS 9.1 Anyway it's working now and that makes me happy^^

Comment: although this is a working solution unfortunately it has a big side effect the ugly visible upscroll even if you are using `viewWillLayoutSubviews` :/

Comment: Trying almost 6 ways for solving the issue, this answer only worked for me in iOS9.x.

Comment: works well even if set it after assigning text for UITextView

Comment: `setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)` will lead to a hard-to-find bug: `layoutManager.boundingRect(forGlyphRange aRange, in container: textContainer)` return wrong frame

Answer (score 46):

This is the only way that worked for me. I disable the scroll of the *UITextView* before the view is loaded and then i enable it again:

```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        yourTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        yourTextView.isScrollEnabled = true
    }
```

Comment: the best solution to have the minimum visible visual effect of the happening up scroll

Comment: Worked fine for me

Comment: I had some cluttering issues when scrolling on iPad by utilising that solution.

Answer (score 27):

```
[self.textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
```

in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 19):

By Programmatically before loading the content disable the scrolling property of textview
       `textview.scrollenabled = NO;`

And after loading enable the scrolling of textview  `textview.scrollenabled = YES;`

As well check the `XIB`, always non-check the scrolling enabled of Textview.

Comment: thanks alot but if we have this uitextview in collectionview or tableview
it will not work

Answer (score 13):

The answers for the question [Blank space at top of UITextView in iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931934/blank-space-at-top-of-uitextview-in-ios-7) provide a much cleaner end user experience.

In `viewDidLoad` of the view controller containing the text view:

```
 self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Setting `textView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0,0), animated: false)` and some of these other suggestions do work when called in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` but on older devices like iPad 2 and older you will actually see the text get scrolled when the screen is displayed. That is not something you want the end user to see.

Answer (score 4):

I was still having problems after using these solutions. The problem definitely seems to relate to having transparent navigation bars and selecting to automatically adjust content insets on the view controller. If you don't care about your text scrolling underneath the navigation bar then it's best to leave these settings off and constrain the top of your textview to the bottom of the navigation bar, rather than to the top of the viewcontroller.

If like me you wanted it to appear underneath your navigation bar when you scroll down; then the solution that worked for me was to add this.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    CGFloat offset = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height+[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;

    [self.textView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -offset) animated:NO];
}
```

This just looks for the height of the navigation bar and status bar and adjusts the content offset accordingly.

Note that one downside of this approach is that when the device rotates you'll end up scrolling back to the top.

Comment: Thank you - this ultimately led me to the right idea :)

Answer (score 4):

For me fine works this code:

```
    textView.attributedText = newText //or textView.text = ...

    //this part of code scrolls to top
    textView.contentOffset.y = -64 //or = 0 if no Navigation Bar
    textView.scrollEnabled = false
    textView.layoutIfNeeded()
    textView.scrollEnabled = true
```

For scroll to exact position and show it on top of screen I use this code:

```
    var scrollToLocation = 50 //<needed position>
    textView.contentOffset.y = textView.contentSize.height
    textView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange.init(location: scrollToLocation, length: 1))
```

Setting contentOffset.y scrolls to the end of text, and then scrollRangeToVisible scrolls up to value of scrollToLocation. Thereby, needed position appears in first line of scrollView.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to some other answers, but with the added benefit that you won't cause a scroll to top on subsequent device rotations. Works well in Swift 2.2

```
/// Whether view has laid out subviews at least once before.
var viewDidLayoutSubviewsAtLeastOnce = false

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if !viewDidLayoutSubviewsAtLeastOnce {
        textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -textView.contentInset.top), animated: false)
    }

    viewDidLayoutSubviewsAtLeastOnce = true
}
```

Comment: After trying a few different answers this one worked the best for me. As per Swindler's answer, you could use CGPointZero for the CGPoint.

Comment: It is important to do this in this method - viewDidLayoutSubviews.  Many answers will have you do this in viewWillAppear, but this is wrong.  viewDidLayoutSubviews is the place to do this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift Version**

A combination of things will be needed:

1.) Set your outlet

```
  @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!
```

2.) In storyboard on View Controller turn off "Adjust Scroll View Insets"

3.) Set content to zero top by adding below to your view controller

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
   super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
     myUITextView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: 'CGPointZero' is unavailable in Swift

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting content offset from **viewDidLayoutSubviews** you can write **layoutIfNeeded** from **viewDidLoad** to set the proper position of textview as below:

```
    self.textView.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
```

Cheers !!

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2, Xcode 7 solution, to leave scroll **Enabled** as well as have the text start at the top, this is all you need:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myUITextView: UITextView!

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    //start scroll at top of text
    myUITextView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))
}
```

Comment: thanks! this worked perfectly for me with Swift 2.2. None of the other solutions here worked as smoothy and simply.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3.0

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    privacyText.isScrollEnabled = false
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    privacyText.isScrollEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: Disable scrolling in Storyboard!
And enable in code.
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    privacyText.isScrollEnabled = true
}

Answer (score 2):

This worked the best for me! I placed this within viewDidLoad().

```
//TextView Scroll starts from the top
myTextView.contentOffset.y = 0
```

Comment: Expression is not assignable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it that always works for me. Objective-C:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.textView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
}
```

And in Swift:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    textView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift version:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    yourTextView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3, 4, 5 solution:**

Steps to solve the issue:

- Disable the UITextView scroll
- set scrollRectToVisible
- enable UITextView scroll

Code:

```
yourTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
let rect:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
yourTextView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: false)
yourTextView.isScrollEnabled = true
```

This Worked for me. Hope that will help!

Comment: Thanks Mohit for a handy easy explanation.

Answer (score 1):

add the following function to your view controller class...

```
Swift 3

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.mainTextView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: false)
}
Swift 2.1

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.mainTextView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: false)
}
Objective C

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [self.mainTextView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
}
```

或者 你在ViewDidAppear 里面加上滚动，这样用户会看到他往上滚动到第一行

Comment: could you please translate the last sentence into English ?

Answer (score 1):

in swift 4 with attributed text any of answer does not help me and i combine some answers in topic.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)
     uiTextview.isScrollEnabled = false
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     uiTextview.isScrollEnabled = true
     uiTextview.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: what about if the uittextview is in collection view or tableview

Comment: @AmrAngry i have no idea, i just used it for text view

Comment: thanks i use  tetxview.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it. I subclassed textview, and:

```
override func willMoveToSuperview(newSuperview: UIView?) {
    self.scrollEnabled = false
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.scrollEnabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From storyboard, select the view controller on which you have you text view placed. In the attributes inspector, uncheck "Adjust Scroll View Insets". That's it.

Answer (score 0):

**Put this code on your class**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        self.About_TV.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: false) // About_TV : your text view name)
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Add code to the viewdidload

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```